# Delete text in input field not working

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have a plus/minus button where you can plug in only numerical values in the input field or click the plus/minus button to select a value. When you go click inside the text field and try to delete or backspace the number it is not working. Here is the html and a link to my fiddle. Update: The delete key works in Chrome but not in Firefox. https://jsfiddle.net/714dxayk/5/

```
<span class="form-title">Quantity</span>
<form id='myform' method='POST' action='#' class="numbo">
<input type='button' value='-' class='qtyminus' field='quantity' style="font-weight: bold; font-size:18px;" />
<input type='text' name='quantity' value='1' class='qty' style="margin-bottom: 0px !important" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'/>
<input type='button' value='+' class='qtyplus' field='quantity' style="font-weight: bold; font-size:18px;" />
</form>
```

Comment: I see no script there, how can you say not working?

Comment: I didn't put the javascript because it is not the problem I am trying to fix.

Comment: I edited my fiddle with the javascript if that helps any.

Comment: `onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'` looks like it would reject all non-numeric keypresses.

Comment: I want to be able for users to put in numerical values only. Removing that allows all values to be typed.

Comment: Apparently you also want them to be able to type backspace.

Comment: @melpomene I want them to be able to delete if they put in a wrong value.

Comment: Your input accepts 0, but the buttons don't allow decrementing beyond 1. Also, users can paste arbitrary text into the input.

Comment: Why are you using key codes rather than the actual value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try assigning a keypress handler to the input field. In the handler, let the browser process specific key presses and ignore other key presses:

```
$('.qty').keypress(function(ev){
    // Don't ignore numbers.
    if (ev.charCode >= 48 && ev.charCode <= 57) {
        return;
    }

    // Don't ignore BS, DEL, and arrow keys.
    switch (ev.keyCode) {
        case 8:   // backspace
        case 46:  // delete key
        case 37:  // arrows
        case 38:
        case 39:
        case 40:
            return;
    }

    // Ignore the rest of the keys.
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```